# I want custom image for back button in navigation bar but got 2 back buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Can someone clever explain me why this is happening?

I have a ViewController `A` and ViewController `B` where `A` does `push()` and `B` is on top.

Inside `A` I have created this code:

```
    private lazy var backBarButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    button.tintColor = .white
    return button
}()
```

This gives me this crazy output :) It's like default iOS arrow + mine next to each other.

[image]

At least it does not have "Back" title which is also something that I need :)

When I change my code to something like that:

```
    private lazy var backBarButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    button.tintColor = .white
    return button
}()
```

I've got arrow (and can modify it's tint), no `title` but it's not the same as my custom image.

[image]

**Why is my custom image simply not replacing the system stock one?**

Answer (score 0):

you can set custom back navigation button by below code :

```
 private lazy var backBarButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    button.tintColor = .white
    return button
}()
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButton
```

Comment: Looks reasonable to me but I've tried this and no changes :/

Answer (score 0):

First I would hide the default back button using

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

And then I can proceed and add a new custom back button on the left items

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```